# LD_PRELOAD in QEMU user space emulation

Tags: qemu, dynamic-linking

I was trying to emulate a firmware and as a part of the process I was interested in knowing what device files are being registered using mknod. In order to intercept those calls I had created a shared object file and just for a dry run, I was trying to preload this shared library while making a call to mknod to register a character device while doing user space emulation with QEMU like so.

> sudo strace chroot . ./qemu-mips-static -E LD_PRELOAD="/mknod.so"
>   mknod chrdev4 100 0

The files are in the correct place and I was following a tutorial very closely so I know am not making a syntactical as such, but my strace log showed my preloaded library not being accessed at all. Please note that in this case, my mknod is a symbolic link to the busybox binary which in turn executes the mknod syscall. I was wondering if that level of indirection could be an issue and possibly a reason as to why my library isn't getting preloaded?

Comment: If I had to guess, adding `-E LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/"` would do the trick. You can have multiple `-E` options. A complete command might look like this: `sudo strace chroot . ./qemu-mips-static -E LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/" -E LD_PRELOAD="mknod.so" mknod chrdev4 100 0`